# How to show dialog immediately without any click?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to show the custom dialog when I start the application and without any event to trigger, e.g. button click. I put the custom dialog in `onCreate()`, but the application crahes for `NullPointerException` at `btnDecline.setOnClickListener`.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnRegister, btnDecline, btnAccept;
    private EditText etRegisterName, etRegisterEmail;
    private Dialog terms;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        btnRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        etRegisterName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRegisterName);
        etRegisterEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etRegisterEmail);

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = etRegisterName.getText().toString();
                String email = etRegisterEmail.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        showTermsConditions();
    }

    private void showTermsConditions(){
        terms = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        terms.setContentView(R.layout.terms_conditions_dialog);
        btnDecline = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDecline);
        btnAccept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAccept);
        terms.setTitle("Terms and Conditions");
        terms.show();

        btnDecline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                moveTaskToBack(true);
            }
        });

        btnAccept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                terms.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried so far for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
terms.setContentView(R.layout.terms_conditions_dialog);
btnDecline = (Button) terms.findViewById(R.id.btnDecline);
btnAccept = (Button) terms.findViewById(R.id.btnAccept);
```

The buttons belong to the `Dialog`. You need to find views in that view hierarchy.

`findViewById` looks for a view in the current view hierarchy. The Buttons `btnDecline` and  `btnAccept` do not belong to `register.xml`. They belong to `terms_conditions_dialog.xml` which is the layout for the Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking buttons id in wrong place

```
private void showTermsConditions(){
        terms = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        terms.setContentView(R.layout.terms_conditions_dialog);
        btnDecline = (Button) terms.findViewById(R.id.btnDecline);
        btnAccept = (Button) terms.findViewById(R.id.btnAccept);
        terms.setTitle("Terms and Conditions");
        terms.show();

        btnDecline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                moveTaskToBack(true);
            }
        });

        btnAccept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                terms.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```